# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unclear which file or line the warning is for

Tags: node.js, es6-promise, unhandled-exception

I have been getting several errors similar to this one:

```
(node:30892) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 5): SyntaxError
```

From these questions ([What is Unhandled Promise Rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500490/what-is-unhandled-promise-rejection) and [NodeJS UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716569/nodejs-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning)) it seems that these warnings are caused by not having a .catch on a promise after a chain of .then

However, these warnings do not have a file or line number where the problem lies. Is there any way to find this out/narrow it down?

Answer (score 3):

You can catch the [`unhandled promise rejection warning`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection), and use the given data to know where it happens.

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
   console.log('Unhandled Rejection at: Promise', p, 'reason:', reason);
});
```

---

This gyus [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9523) tell us :

[image]

Comment: This prints out: "console.log src\App\app.jsx:9 unhandledRejection" where line 9 is the location of the console.log in process.on, not the location of the actual warning. Logging error instead of error.message gives a trace which is unhelpful. Any ideas?

Comment: I got this error:
  console.log src\App\app.jsx:9
    Unhandled Rejection at: Promise reason: SyntaxError
        at XMLHttpRequest.open (<SOME PATH>\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xmlhttprequest.js:486:15)
        at dispatchXhrRequest (<SOME PATH>\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:45:13)
        at xhrAdapter (<SOME PATH>\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:12:10)
        at dispatchRequest (<SOME PATH>\node_modules\axios\lib\core\dispatchRequest.js:52:10)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)

Is this the actual source of the error?

Comment: To be fair Idk. I've never used it before, but it seems to be the correct answer looking at the github answer.

Comment: This definitely helped, but the upshot is that the line/file that the error originally happened in is not displayed in my case when using this method.