# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning Testing Promise Rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, jasmine, jasmine-node

I'm trying to write a jasmine test that has a spy which `.and.returnValues` a list of promises. The first several promises are rejections, the last is a success. While the test passes just fine, Node complains with the following:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): undefined
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): undefined
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4): undefined
PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 2)
PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 3)
PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 4)
```

My code is very straight forward: I create a spy, inject it into my code, call my code which will loop calling my spy until it doesn't reject, and then monitor that it was called 5 times. The spy is like this:

```js
var spy = jasmine.createSpy("spy").and.returnValues(
    Promise.reject(),
    Promise.reject(),
    Promise.reject(),
    Promise.reject(),
    Promise.resolve(true)
);

// Inject the spy...

// This will resolve only when the Promise-returning function it calls resolves without rejecting.
myFunc()   
    .then(() => {
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(5);
        done();
    })
    .catch();
```

The code under test has last in it's chain an empty `.catch()` to validate that I'm not causing the problem there. AFICT, the problem is that Node sees me doing `Promise.reject()` and thinks that is unhandled, when, in fact, it is handled.

How can I properly test rejected promises? I feel like I need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40168660/271351) for Jasmine.

Comment: why don't you use `async await`, wrap the `await` in a `try..catch..finally` block , in the `finally` block then you can do `expect(spy).toHaveBeenCaledTimes(5)`;

Comment: I'm on Node 6, where `async/await` isn't supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you catch the rejected promise somewhere later in the event queue and not in the same call stack where the promise is created.

A solution for this is:

```js
var unsafeReject = p => {
  p.catch(ignore=>ignore);
  return p;
};

var p = Promise.reject("will cause warning");

//will catch reject on queue, not on stack
setTimeout(
  ()=>p.catch(e=>console.log("reject:",e))
);

var q = unsafeReject(Promise.reject("will NOT cause warning"));
setTimeout(
  ()=>q.catch(e=>console.log("reject:",e))
);
```

Comment: Did you mean `safeReject`?

Comment: @Bergi Correct, actually the name is wrong, should be `unsafeReject` since the promise passed in will not "blow up" in the console when it's rejected but can still be caught on the returned promise. I'll rename it to `unsafeReject`

Comment: I guess I'd use either `handled(Promise.reject(…))` or `handledRejection(…)`. I would not use the "safe" terminology, as it's ambiguous whether it's safe to reject (without blowing anything up) or safe because you cannot miss rejections.