# Node: Mocha/Chai Shows UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning While All Tests Pass

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, es6-promise, chai

### Apparently Very Strange Behavior in MochaJS/ChaiJS

#### Context

I am having a very peculiar problem with something rather straight-forward. **The error actually demarcates a line in the module being tested**, but I have hunted, scouted, and crusaded for the error and nothing *seems* to be wrong with the module. This is after being broken out into its own file, as I assumed it was my test subject's code, after a similar error to this occurred alongside several random other ones where nothing *seemed* to be wrong. The module has been through such heavy refactoring because of this (*it has actually been rewritten now*) -- **and** it contradicts with real, working code -- that I am extremely certain that this is an issue with Mocha, Chai, or how I am leveraging such to write tests.

There are 3 scenarios to note:

- a) `it("should do x", () => {...})`
- b) `it("should do y", () => {...})`
- c) `it("should do x", () => {...})` **and** `it("should do y", () => {...})`

Something **important to note** is that the assertion code for *a* and *b* are **exactly the same** -- they are exact copies. Moreover, when I replace the [basic, straight-forward, synchronous] assertion code for a & b with simple `expect(true).to.equal(true|false)`, I do not receive the error. This suggests that I am staging my tests incorrectly.

**`*/**/*.spec.js`**

---

**(a)**

```
describe("Something", () => {

    it("should do x", () => {
        // constructs an object, sets some data, runs assertions.
    });

    //it("should do y", () => {
    //    // constructs an object, sets some data, runs assertions.
    //});

});
```

**(b)**

```
describe("Something", () => {

    //it("should do x", () => {
    //    // constructs an object, sets some data, runs assertions.
    //});

    it("should do y", () => {
        // constructs an object, sets some data, runs assertions.
    });

});
```

**(c)**

```
describe("Something", () => {

    it("should do x", () => {
        // constructs an object, sets some data, runs assertions.
    });

    it("should do y", () => {
        // constructs an object, sets some data, runs assertions.
    });

});
```

#### Problem

Scenarios *a* and *b* will succeed; scenario *c* fails. In other words, commenting out one test or the other allows the suite to pass, while having them *both* running leads to the suite failing.

#### Question

What are common or uncommon possibilities for this strange behavior?

#### Details

```
$ mocha


0 passing (5ms)



Delegations Manager (Routes & Policies)
    √ should set routes
    √ should set policies
(node:17972) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'policies' of undefined
    at DelegationsManager.map (C:\Users\Cody\projects\frameworks\motorman\src\motorman\delegations-manager.js:119:45)
    at routes.map (C:\Users\Cody\projects\frameworks\motorman\src\motorman\delegations-manager.js:99:53)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at DelegationsManager.generate (C:\Users\Cody\projects\frameworks\motorman\src\motorman\delegations-manager.js:99:36)
    at ready.then (C:\Users\Cody\projects\frameworks\motorman\src\motorman\delegations-manager.js:78:35)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:17972) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:17972) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
    √ should be ready when both routes and policies have been set
    √ should be stable when delegations bear delegates


4 passing (49ms)

@Conductor: finished execution with { code: 1, failures: 0 }
```

*Any **1** of the tests above will pass without throwing the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`, however, running anymore than just 1 will throw the exception*.

Comment: could you show the promise in your test? and do you use chai-as-promised?

Comment: Have you look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716569/nodejs-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning

Comment: did you use same source of data for both of test? if yes, have you tried to reset the data using beforeEach()?