# Docusign timeout issue for Envelope - NodeJs

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I am using **docusign-esign** package in my project for esigning.

While creating an envelope, I am getting the below error-

(node:3254) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Timeout of 60000ms exceeded

Please let me know if any way I can configure the timeout value or any other way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

60s is a very long time and I would not try to edit the timeout but rather debug the code before createEnvelope call. Even start with the ApiClent. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716569/getting-a-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-when-testing-using-mocha-chai) suggest that the error could be caused by faulty assertion