# What is UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, unhandled-promise-rejection

I've pasted two almost same codes with one little difference, one works just fine but the other gives *UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning*.

```
async function promise () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    throw new Error();
    resolve();
    reject();
  })
}

promise().then((data) =>{console.log('then')}).catch((err)=>{console.log('from the catch')});
```

The output is :

```
> node index.js
from the catch
```

But for this case

```
function promise () {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    throw new Error();
    resolve();
    reject();
  })
}

promise().then((data) =>{console.log('then')}).catch((err)=>{console.log('err')});
```

The output is something like this

```
> node index.js
(node:98195) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error
    at /home/parthiv/Projects/exp/index.js:47:11
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promise (/home/parthiv/Projects/exp/index.js:46:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/parthiv/Projects/exp/index.js:53:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:98195) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:98195) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Can someone explain this behaviour of an async function inside the promise ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49664398/14032355

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've passed an `async` function into a Promise constructor, which is not the right thing to do. The return value of the `async` function is what is unhandled.

The Promise constructor is designed for synchronous usage, and it completely disregards its return value. If you `throw` in the function you pass to a Promise constructor, the Promise constructor will return a rejected promise; that's the behavior you see in your first example. If the function returns a value, even a Promise, it won't matter: [the value is discarded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise#parameters).

> About the executor, it’s important to understand the following:
>
> - The executor return value is ignored.
> - If an error is thrown in the executor, the promise is rejected.

`async` functions convert its `return` and `throw` calls to Promise resolution, but `async` functions *always* return a Promise. So in your second example, your `throw` results in a rejected Promise, *which is then unhandled*; the return value is discarded entirely as above. If it weren't for the UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning, your `throw new Error()` would have no symptoms, and the promise your `promise()` returned would never resolve.

If you want `promise()` to return a promise, you can just return the return value of the inner `async` function, or (even better) make `promise()` itself an async function. If you do need the `resolve`/`reject` calls, you can always `return new Promise()` from inside the function; whenever an `async` function or `.then()` handler returns a Promise, that return value is unwrapped.